# Lookup inside mutate pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, lookup, mutate

I have a tibble (*counts_table)* that has the amount of times each item is repeated in the dataset:

| item | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 6 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 3 |

In my working dataset, I have the also the variable *item*, along with many others. I want to change one particular (*amount*) and I wanted it scaled down, divided over however many times the item has been repeated.

I thought of using mutate() within a pipe, but I get stuck when trying to define some sort of lookup function. In pseudocode:

- Look up the item by its name in the *counts_table* tibble, and find the associated count (say *n*)
- Then mutate the *amount* to *amount* / *n*

I'm really struggling to define the lookup within the pipe. I have tried with:

```
df %>%
  mutate(amount = amount / counts_table[counts_table$item == item, "count"])
```

But I get the following error:

```
✖ Logical subscript `counts_table$item == item` must be size 1 or 287, not 3768. 
ℹ longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

When the second bit is run on its own:

```
counts_table[counts_table$item == "string", "count"]
```

It does give me the value from the *counts_table* tibble (say 6), so why does it not apply the 6 to the mutate function in the pipe?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. So you've shown us `df` but not `counts_table`? It seems like it would be better just to `inner_join` them and then do the mutation.

Comment: Your reasoning doesn't work because mutate does not by default operate on a row-by-row basis. Most functions in R are vectorized and they run on the entire column of data all at once. Then means you don't just get one `item` at a time, it passed in the entire column. This allows the code to run more efficiently but you have to make sure your expressions are vector-friendly as a result. What you wrote is more similar to `counts_table[counts_table$item == df$item, "count"]`

Answer (score 2):

Absent a reproducible example, I think this is worth a shot:

```
library(dplyr)
df |> left_join(counts_table |> select(item, count),
                by = c("item" = "item")) |>
  mutate(amount = amount/count) |>
  select(-count)
```

testing:

```
df <- data.frame(item = LETTERS[1:4],
                 amount = c(600,300,300,900))

counts_table <- data.frame(item = LETTERS[1:4],
                           count = c(6,3,3,3))
# gives
  item amount
1    A    100
2    B    100
3    C    100
4    D    300
```

Edit: this assumes all possble (`item`s) appear in the `counts_table` - otherwise you will get `NA`s.

Comment: This seems to me like the canonical dplyr approach: join to get the variables you need, then mutate with those variables.